# distinct cases for two variables by grouping and counting

Tags: r

We can use the following data frame as an example:

```
Case <- c("Siddhartha", "Siddhartha", "Siddhartha", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Hannah", "Herbert")
Procedure <- c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "1", "1")
Location <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a")

(df <- data.frame(Case, Procedure, Location))

        Case Procedure Location
1 Siddhartha         1        a
2 Siddhartha         1        a
3 Siddhartha         2        b
4       Paul         3        a
5       Paul         3        a
6       Paul         4        b
7     Hannah         1        c
8    Herbert         1        a
```

Now i do the following:

```
df %>% 
  count(Location, Procedure) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Procedure     a     b     c
  <fct>     <int> <int> <int>
1 1             3     0     1
2 3             2     0     0
3 2             0     1     0
4 4             0     1     0
```

This is not exactly, what i want though. What i want is the following data frame:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Procedure     a     b     c
  <fct>     <int> <int> <int>
1 1             2     0     1
2 3             1     0     0
3 2             0     1     0
4 4             0     1     0
```

Notice the difference in Procedure 1 and 3.

So what i would like is a function, that counts the number of DISTINCT cases for each Procedures AND each location. Also that function should be working on varying data frames, where there are different (unknown) cases and procedures.

For the original data frame

```
df %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  count(Location, Procedure) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

does not work, since it is ignoring the "distinct". What works (also for the original data frame!) is the following:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Procedure, Location) %>%
  summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case))
```

That gives me the following though:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Procedure [4]
  Procedure Location Anzahl
  <fct>     <fct>     <int>
1 1         a             2
2 1         c             1
3 2         a             1
4 3         b             1
5 4         b             1
```

But how to implement the "pivot_wider" function, so it is also sorted by location? If i try to add it, i get the following error:

"Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`."

Also it is very confusing to me, why the solution of Ronak works for the example data frame but not for the original. I can't spot important differences in these two data frames.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to add `distinct` or `unique` before counting

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  count(Location, Procedure) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  Procedure     a     b     c
#  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 1             2     0     1
#2 3             1     0     0
#3 2             0     1     0
#4 4             0     1     0
```

---

For OP's data they need :

```
df %>% 
 group_by(Procedure, Location) %>% 
 summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = Anzahl, 
             values_fill = list(Anzahl = 0))
```

Comment: how does R know, which variable i want to be distinct or unique?

Comment: If you don't specify any variables it selects all the variables in the dataframe.

Comment: in the original data frame it works but only for the first procedure. in every following procedure it ignores that i only want the unique cases. very confusing to me

Comment: Hmmm...since this works on the data shared can you find what is the difference between the data you have shared and your real data?

Comment: it has more locations and more cases. Also a case is always bound to a single location, unlike in the example i shared.

Comment: @Dutschke Can you try `df %>%
  group_by(Procedure, Location) %>%
  summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = Anzahl, values_fill = list(Anzahl = 0))` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single call to `pivot_wider` and take advantage of the argument `values_fn`, which applies a function to the values

```
df %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = Location, 
             values_from = Case, 
             values_fn = list(Case = n_distinct), 
             values_fill = list(Case = 0))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
>   Procedure     a     b     c
>   <fct>     <int> <int> <int>
> 1 1             2     0     1
> 2 2             0     1     0
> 3 3             1     0     0
> 4 4             0     1     0
> ```

Comment: If i use this function on my original data frame, it doesnt give me a new data frame. it just adds a few columns with the different locations but also dismisses some other random columns.

Comment: Then the example you shared does not reflect the data frame you have. Consider sharing an example that does this problem

Comment: I thought i did exactly that. The original data frame has a few more columns, but they shouldn't be of interest, when not mentioned in the function, right?