# add columns to data frames for values in existing column

Tags: r

The data frame:

```
Case <- c("Siddhartha", "Siddhartha", "Siddhartha", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Hannah", "Herbert", "Herbert")
Procedure <- c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1")
Location <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a")

(df <- data.frame(Case, Procedure, Location))

        Case Procedure Location
1 Siddhartha         1        a
2 Siddhartha         1        a
3 Siddhartha         2        a
4       Paul         3        b
5       Paul         3        b
6       Paul         4        b
7     Hannah         1        c
8    Herbert         1        a
9    Herbert         1        a
```

The function:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Procedure, Location) %>%
  summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Anzahl))
```

The result:

```
  Procedure Location Anzahl
  <fct>     <fct>     <int>
1 1         a             2
2 1         c             1
3 2         a             1
4 3         b             1
5 4         b             1
```

What i need:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Procedure     a     b     c
  <fct>     <int> <int> <int>
1 1             2     0     1
2 2             1     0     0
3 3             0     1     0
4 4             0     1     0
```

So i want to sort the data frame by procedures AND locations. This is what i tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Procedure, Location) %>%
  summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

But: Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`.

I tried to solve this problem in other questions i asked before (almost feels like spamming at this point), but i can't apply the solutions to the original data frame. The function shown above (group_by, summarize) is what also works for the original. The only thing is, that it doesn't sort it for locations.

Regards

Comment: Didn't I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952557/distinct-cases-for-two-variables-by-grouping-and-counting/61952747#61952747)?

Comment: sadly no. it completely messes with the original data frame

Comment: So you re-posted the question? I don't get it.  Why not just update the other one?

Comment: Use values_from = 'Anzahl' instead of 'n', because n does not exist. Same for values_fill.

Comment: i tried another approach, so its easier to understand. Another approach with what is already working on the original data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Procedure, Location) %>% 
  summarise(Anzahl = n_distinct(Case)) %>%
  arrange(Location, desc(Anzahl)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from = Anzahl, values_fill = list(Anzahl = 0))
```

Which gives us:

```
  Procedure     a     b     c
  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
1 1             2     0     1
2 2             1     0     0
3 3             0     1     0
4 4             0     1     0
```

Comment: In order to get the `Procedure` values in order `a`, `b`, `c` add `arrange(Location, desc(Anzahl))` between the `summarise` and the `pivot_wider` statement

Comment: Thanks @RicS didn't realize the cols were out of order. I updated the post with your fix.